# Hover image to display text in other div

Tags: javascript, css, html, hover

I have a sequence of 5 different images each in a separate div. Underneath these, I have another div which I intend to fill with text depending on whatever image is hovered.

The idea is that each image when hovered will fill this text div with the relevant information. I would also like for this div to animate so that it starts off with height 0 and expand it to 150px then add the text and when mouse is moved off image it should collapse.

There is a footer underneath this area so I cant just hide it and then show when hovered.

Is there a neat way to do this with JavaScript / JQuery ?

Thanks

Edit:

I have put something together myself to try and solve this but there are a couple of issues

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){    
        $("#upper").hover(
            function(){
                $('#caption').animate({'height': '150px'}, 1500);
                $('#caption').html('Tesrtssadwa');
            }, 
            function(){
                $('#caption').stop().animate({'height': '0px'}, 1500);
            }
        );
}
);
```

So this does pretty much what I want with a couple of issues. If I quickly hover over the div a few times it will queue the animations. I would ideally like for this not to happen. Is there an easy way to do this or would it be more hassle than its worth ?

Also, at one point I managed to have the div collapsed but the text was still showing. I haven't been able to reproduce this but is there a way to make the text fade as the div collapses?

```
$('#caption').html('');
```

looks a bit bad

Edit: I can reproduce it. Hovering over image until it expands fully, then moving off of it will collapse the div and the text will reappear.

Comment: Yes, I always try something before I post here. Look at my other posts. I didn't post it because it wasn't doing what I wanted (read anything) and didn't want to have people trying to fix code that wasn't working rather than just spamming out a simpler approach. Regardless, what you wrote wasn't constructive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll likely be interested in the [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/), [mouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/), [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/), and [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) functions. If I understand correctly, something like this is what you're looking for:

```
$("#picture1").mouseover(function() {
        $("#textdiv").slideDown().html("This is information about picture 1. It is the first picture."
}).mouseout(function() {
        $("#textdiv").slideUp();
});

$("#picture2").mouseover(function() {
        $("#textdiv").slideDown().html("This is information about picture 2. It is the second picture."
}).mouseout(function() {
        $("#textdiv").slideUp();
});

$("#picture3").mouseover(function() {
    $("#textdiv").slideDown().html("This is information about picture 3. It is the last picture."
}).mouseout(function() {
    $("#textdiv").slideUp();
});
```

Comment: @Predz: If this helped, would you mind marking it as the accepted answer to your question via the checkmark to the left?